# Make file error when compiling kernel module

Tags: c, makefile, linux-kernel, debian, kernel-module

Hello i am trying to compile my first kernel module but i am receiving an error message. The hello.c program for my module is shown below:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");

static int hello_init(void){
printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello, world\n");
return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void){
printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye, cruel world\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

My makefile is the following:

```
obj-m := hello.o
KDIR := /lib/modules/4.19.94-ti-r42/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)

default:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD)
```

I also want to mention that i tried to replace `M=$(PWD)` with `SUBDIRS=$(PWD)` but i still received the same error. 
When i run my make file i receive the following error message:

```
debian@beaglebone:~/LDD-3$ make
make -C /lib/modules/4.19.94-ti-r42/build M=/home/debian/LDD-3
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.94-ti-r42'
scripts/Makefile.build:45: /home/debian/LDD-3/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/debian/LDD-3/Makefile'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1522: _module_/home/debian/LDD-3] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.94-ti-r42'
make: *** [makefile:6: default] Error 2
```

Does anyone know what i may be doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named your makefile `makefile`, as we can see from this message:

```
make: *** [makefile:6: default] Error 2
```

The kernel build system expects your makefile to be named `Makefile`, as can be seen in this message:

```
scripts/Makefile.build:45: /home/debian/LDD-3/Makefile: No such file or directory
```

So I suggest you use:

```
mv makefile Makefile
```